# Determining DIALSTATUS after executing dial from AGI

Tags: asterisk

I am an asterisk newbie. Currently I want to dial some number from my AGI server using exec("Dial",..) command and I would like to be able to know when no one's answering the call by checking DIALSTATUS == noanswer.
I have tried transferring the dial command to the dialplan and getting the DIALSTATUS from there but its always empty. I have tried getting the DIALSTATUS in the AGI but it didnt work.

example:

first try:

```
public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel)
{
exec("Dial","SIP/" + "7004" + ",60,G(from-internal-custom,1301,1)");

String dialStatus = request.getParameter("DIALSTATUS");
exec("NoOp","dial status is = " + dialStatus); //it is always empty (i think its
because the moment the first dialplan goes to the AGI,DIALSTATUS is not
initialized yet since I havent even issued dial command)
}
```

second try:

in the dialplan:

```
exten => 1301,1,NoOp(dial status is = ${DIALSTATUS})
exten => 1301,2,NoOp(dial status is = ${DIALSTATUS})
exten => 1301,3,NoOp(dial status is = ${DIALSTATUS})
exten => 1301,4,NoOp(dial status is = ${DIALSTATUS})

//all of them is empty
```

so how can I get the value of DIALSTATUS if I issue the dial command from AGI?
thank you so much for the kind answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use GetVariable agi command call.

There are no way say how it have look in your framework, becuase you not informed about it.